# Assign a Resetting Per-Parent Incrementing Column to Each Child Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, composite-primary-key

I have two tables, a `SalesOrderHeader` that has an identity primary key `TxnID` column and a `TxnNumber` column that I obtain from external software. For example sake I will omit any other columns and lets say the values in the first 3 rows are like so:

| TxnID | TxnNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 00001 |
| 2 | 00002 |
| 3 | 00003 |
| ... | ... |

Then I have a `SalesOrderDetail` table where `TxnNumber` is a foreign key. I would like for `TxnDetailID` to behave as follows:

| TxnDetailID | TxnNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 00001 |
| 2 | 00001 |
| 1 | 00002 |
| ... | ... |

Basically kind of act as an identity but on the `TxnNumber` basis, resetting back to 1 once `TxnNumber` changes. Is there a way to do so in SQL Server so that it will be continuously follow this rule on data insertion? Because I would like to make a composite primary key that is defined something like: `TxnNumber`-`TxnDetailID`

Comment: There's no automatic way, but you can of course precalculate TxnDetailID on insert yourself, probably easiest

Comment: This sounds unecessary and just adds complication, what does it matter to the database what the number is other that it's unique? What do you gain from a sequence starting at 1 for each number - you can't guarantee they will always be sequential without gaps for example.

Comment: Keys should ideally have no user/human meaning. You will cause yourself a world of pain if you try and align PK/FK/HK (HK = Human Key). Let the database do its thing with auto-inc PK's and FK's and then work out you HK as your desire.

Comment: In many cases this is done within SELECT using the ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Anyway, simple UPDATE TxDetailID = x.RN FROM (SELECT using ROW_NUMBER) x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do so in SQL Server so that it will be continuously follow this rule on data insertion?

No.  Just use an IDENTITY column or SEQUENCE.  They only ways to do this create needless complexity and impair concurrency.

And if you need it for display you can use `ROW_NUMBER over (order by TxnDetailID)`, or similar.